# how to set limit of selected image items in list used image picker package? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to set limit list for selected multiple images and keep listing that all have 4 images to used image picker in flutter

```
List<XFile> imageFileList = [];
void selectImage() async {
  final List<XFile>? selectedImages = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
  if (selectedImages!.isNotEmpty ) {
    imageFileList.addAll(selectedImages);
  } 
setState(() {});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`imagePicker` does not allow selecting a specific count.you can do a heck like this

```
List<XFile> imageFileList = [];
void selectImage() async {
   final List<XFile>? selectedImages = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
  if(imageFileList.length>4){
       showASnackBarOrDialogThatUserNotAlowwedMoreThan4();
       return;
    }
  if (selectedImages!.isNotEmpty ) {
     imageFileList.addAll(selectedImages);
    } 
   setState(() {});
 }
```